# LiveData Transformation not getting triggered

Tags: android-room, android-livedata

I subscribed to `ids` and `search` in the ui but i wasn't getting any results so i stepped through with the debugger and found out that the transformation is not getting triggered after the first time. So when i call `setIds` the first time `ids` gets updated but for every call after the first one the transformation won't trigger. Same goes for the `search`.

Any ideas what might possible go wrong?

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val repository = Repository.sharedInstance

    var recentRadius: LiveData<List<RecentRadius>>?
    var recentRoute: LiveData<List<RecentRoute>>?

    init {
        recentRadius = repository.recentRadius()
        recentRoute = repository.recentRoute()
    }


    private val idsInput = MutableLiveData<String>()
    fun setIdsInput(textId: String) {
        idsInput.value = textId
    }

    val ids: LiveData<List<String>> = Transformations.switchMap(idsInput) { id ->
        repository.ids(id)
    }

    private val searchInput = MutableLiveData<Search>()
    fun setSearchInput(search: Search) {
        searchInput.value = search
    }


    val search: LiveData<SearchResult> = Transformations.switchMap(searchInput) { search ->
        when (search.type) {
            SearchType.ID -> repository.id(search)
            SearchType.RADIUS -> repository.radius(search)
            SearchType.ROUTE -> repository.route(search)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The most common reason why transformation don't get triggered is because the there is no `Observer` observing it or the input `LiveData` is not getting changed.

Comment: @AkshayChordiya Thank you this helped me resolve my problem. I registered my fragments in their `onCreate()` but i switched through them which caused the observer to get lost.

Comment: I'll post it as answer so other people will be able to find the root cause

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The most common reason why transformation don't get triggered is when there is no `Observer` observing it or the input `LiveData` is not getting changed.

Comment: Why transformation requires another observer to trigger although Fragment/Activity is subscribed to `ids ` updates?  I don't understand that part here. Why I have to subscribe `idsInput ` LiveData to make `transformation` works?

Comment: `Transformations` are designed in that, they apply the given function on the main thread to each value emitted by `source` LiveData.
That means the function passed is executed only when the value changes.

Comment: But they dont' trigger when you attach observer for the first time. They only trigger when the values change.

Answer (score 0):

Below example illustrates use of map when observer is attached in the activity.

**Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var mBinding : ActivityMainBinding

private val mViewModel : MainViewModel by lazy {
   getViewModel { MainViewModel(this.application) }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
   mBinding.vm = mViewModel

   // adding obeserver
   mViewModel.videoName.observe(this, Observer<String> { value ->
       value?.let {
           //Toast.makeText(this, it, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       }
   })
 }
}
```

**ViewModel** with map

```
class MainViewModel(val appContext : Application) : AndroidViewModel(appContext) {

   private val TAG = "MainViewModel"

   var videoData = MutableLiveData<VideoDownload>()
   var videoName : LiveData<String>

   init {
      // Update the data
      videoName = Transformations.map(videoData) { "updated : "+it.webUrl }
    }

    fun onActionClick(v : View) {
       // change data
       videoData.value = VideoDownload(System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
    }

    fun onReActionClick(v : View) {
       // check data
       Toast.makeText(appContext, videoName.value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

**ViewModel** with switchMap

```
class MainViewModel(val appContext : Application) : AndroidViewModel(appContext) {

    private val TAG = "MainViewModel"

    var videoData = MutableLiveData<VideoDownload>()
    var videoName : LiveData<String>

    init {
       // Update the data
       videoName = Transformations.switchMap(videoData) { modData(it.webUrl) }

    }

    private fun modData(str: String): LiveData<String> {
        val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
        liveData.value = "switchmap : "+str
        return liveData
    }

    fun onActionClick(v : View) {
        // change data
        videoData.value = VideoDownload(System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
    }

    fun onReActionClick(v : View) {
        // check data
        Toast.makeText(appContext, videoName.value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, it was because the observer owner was a fragment. It stopped triggering when navigating to different fragments. I changed the observer owner to the activity and it triggered as expected.

```
itemsViewModel.items.observe(requireActivity(), Observer {
```

The view model was defined as a class property:

```
    private val itemsViewModel: ItemsViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ItemsViewModel::class.java)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it to be triggered.

```
fun <X, Y> LiveData<X>.forceMap(
    mapFunction: (X) -> Y
): LiveData<Y> {
    val result = MutableLiveData<Y>()
    this.observeForever {x->
        if (x != null) {
            result.value = mapFunction.invoke(x)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```